# OpenMP and parallellization problem

Tags: linux, fortran, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, gfortran

I am doing research on computational electromagnetics laboratory with supercomputers. Here, we are working with clusters to solve problems includes over 500M unknowns. At this point we have a problem with parallelizing all these calculations. Until now, we have been working with MPI to communicate among nodes, however, we are about to decide using OpenMP to enable communication between processors in a node in terms of benefits of OpenMP. Notwithstanding, we could not get any efficiency from openMP(probably because of the false coding). Actually the point is I don't know what is the wrong with the code I will give.

It tooks the same time with sequential pure code without any OpenMP directives. When I use 'top' command 8 processors was working with %100 performance during the paralllel section.

gfortran --version | head -1 GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)

```
PROGRAM dotproduct
    USE omp_lib   
    IMPLICIT none 

    INTEGER ::h,m,i,TID,NTHREADS,j,ierr

    REAL :: start,end
    REAL, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:,:) :: a
    REAL, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: x
    REAL, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: b

    m= 20000
    OPEN(UNIT=1,FILE='matrix20000.dat',STATUS='UNKNOWN')
    OPEN(UNIT=2,FILE='vector20000.dat',STATUS='UNKNOWN')

    ALLOCATE(a(m,m)) 
    ALLOCATE(x(m))
    ALLOCATE(b(m))
    REWIND(1)
    REWIND(2)

    WRITE(*,*) ' Reading is just started'

    READ(1,*), a(:,:) 
    READ(2,*), x(:)

    WRITE(*,*) ' Reading is over'
    WRITE(*,*) ' Calculating will be started after parallelization'

    !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(i,TID,j),SHARED(NTHREADS,m,a,x,b)
    TID= omp_get_thread_num()
    IF(TID == 0) THEN
      NTHREADS = OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS()
      PRINT*, 'Starting matrix multiple example with', NTHREADS
    END IF
    CALL cpu_time(start)
    !$OMP DO
          DO i=1, m
             b(i)= 0
             DO j=1, m
                b(i) = b(i)+ a(i,j)*x(j)
             END DO
          END DO
    !$OMP END DO
    !$OMP END PARALLEL
    CALL cpu_time(end)

    WRITE(*,*) end-start,' seconds'

    !DO i=1,m
    !   WRITE(*,*) b(i)
    !END DO

    DEALLOCATE(a)                     !----Deallocation
    DEALLOCATE(x)
    DEALLOCATE(b)


    END PROGRAM dotproduct
```

Comment: The OMP support Redhat back ported to gcc 4.1 was notorious for poor performance. I would recommend looking at a more modern compiler before doing anything else.

Comment: May gcc 4.1 be the main reason of this poor performance. Actually is it correct to called it "poor performance" because it looks like there is no paralellization..

Comment: Just comes to my mind, how exactly do you measure the runtime? If you use the output from cpu_time, you will get the accumulated time of all threads. If you use MPI anyway, you should use MPI_wtime instead to get the actual real time. Regarding the Compilers, I do not believe the GCC implementation would be too bad, even in 4.1, still switching the compiler might improve also the OpenMP scaling.

Comment: m= 2000 that matrix is 20000*20000

Comment: I use both cpu_time and mechanical chronometer to measure time. But I can realize that sequential and this openmp code was taken the same time in chronometer.

Answer (score 1):

Classic error - Cpu_time typically measures the total CPU time, which means it is summed across all the threads! Hence perfect speed up results in a constant time irrespective of the number of threads

Try measuring wall time with system_clock or similar and see what you get.

BTW - why is nthreads shared? It's best to keep as much private as possible

(sorry if this appears twice, first effort ...)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a conflicting memory accessing problem. All processes access the shared x(j). Though it is no real solution, you might try to duplicate x on each thread, to see if this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicating x on each thread, how can I ?

Comment: Having something like x(j,tid) with the same content for each tid.

Comment: Maybe this: http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/mxv_open_mp/mxv_open_mp.f90 is also of interest for you, they have a workshare version of the matrix vector multiply with OpenMP.

Comment: Yes, I see, thank you for your time. However the point I missed is that why telling " PRIVATE(i,TID,j),SHARED(NTHREADS,m,a,x,b)" is causing trouble? I want to make processors calculate i and j privately, but a,x,b should be shared. Where is the wrong thing.

Comment: Nothing wrong, it is just that the concurrent access to the same memory might cause performance degrading.

Comment: Do you think that may it be a solution to upgrade version of compiler from GCC 4.1 to ICC(for clusters using Intel processors) to deal with the performance degrading. Because, the code I wrote is completely proper